# dovecot LMTP proxy not logging anything

Tags: logging, proxy, postfix-mta, dovecot

I posted this issue/question on the official dovecot mailing list almost a year ago sadly without any solution, therefore I would like to post it here in case someone can assist me:

https://dovecot.org/list/dovecot/2017-December/110210.html

I have 2 servers, **server_A** and **server_B**.

**server_A** receives email using postfix, and gives it to dovecot using LMTP that is on the same server **server_A**.

dovecot on **server_A** then proxies it to dovecot on **server_B** using LMTP where it is stored in the users mailbox.

Everything is perfectly logged on **server_A**, both postfix and dovecot entries.

Most of the times, there is nothing logged for that email on **server_B**, but it is stored in users mailbox.

Email delivery is working perfectly, but logging is not consistent. Sometimes I can find the email in the logs on **server_B** but most of the times I can't.

Additional info:

I have a **testing environment that has identical setup** as the **server_A** and **server_B** scenario I mentioned above, I can see the **same issue**.

Logging is done via **rsyslog** on both servers and it is setup like this:

mail.* /var/log/maillog

same as on **server_A** where logging is working perfectly.

I was suspecting that there is a bug in dovecot and I waited to perform an **upgrade from 2.2.11 to 2.2.33.2**. However, I have the **same issue even after the upgrade**, on both testing and production environments.

I also tried skipping rsyslog by setting up dovecot logging directly into a file on **server_B** and I have the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer,

Syslog was limiting number of messages that can be written to the log in a designated time interval. I removed the limits by adding these lines in the /etc/rsyslog.conf file:

```
$ModLoad imuxsock

$SystemLogRateLimitInterval 0
$SystemLogRateLimitBurst 0
```

There was a neat error message in my /var/log/messages log file that pointed me in the right dirrection:

```
imuxsock lost 354 messages from pid 157711 due to rate-limiting
```